# How to call a function correctly when I call her from app?

Tags: python, class, oop, kivy, kivy-language

I have a function that display saved words on screen named `block_screen`. If I call it in my **.kv** file by clicking button in BlockScreen like `root.d_sl()`, then it works good. But, I want this to display when I open this screen, not when I press the button on this screen to do it. So I call this BlockScreen like 'b' in App and use it in my `home_screen` like `app.b.d_sl()`, and it make only print part and not displaying words.

#### Code

```
.py file:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
import slovar

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

...screens....

class OpenScreen(Screen):
    def ob_slova(self):
        self.ids.text_label.text = slovar.slova_obichnie()
        f = open('nicknames.txt', 'a')
        f.write(self.ids.text_label.text + '\n')
        f.close()

class BlockScreen(Screen):
    def d_sl(self):
        self.ids.label_text.text = "ppp"
        f1 = open('nicknames.txt', 'r')
        for i in f1:
            self.ids.label_text.text += i
        f1.close()
        if self.ids.label_text.text == "":
            print('p')
        else:
            print(self.ids.label_text.text)


GUI = Builder.load_file('game.kv')
class GameApp(App):
    b = BlockScreen()
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']                
        screen_manager.current = screen_name

GameApp().run()
```

```
homescreen.kv file:
#:kivy 1.10.1
<HomeScreen>:
    Button:
         size_hint: .7, .1
         pos_hint:{"x":.15, "y":.47}
         background_normal: 'kn1.png'
         text: "HISTORY"
         font_size: self.height - 20
         valign: 'middle'
         halign: 'center'
         padding_x: 56,56
         on_release:
             app.change_screen('block_screen')
             app.b.d_sl()
```

```
blockscreen.kv file:
#:kivy 1.10.1
<BlockScreen>:
    Button:
        text: "Z"
        font_size: self.height - 24
        valign: 'center'
        halign: 'center'
        padding: 2,2
        size_hint: .5, .08
        pos_hint: {'x':.5, 'y':.0}
        background_normal: 'kn2.png'
        on_release:
            root.d_sl()
```

```
main kv file:
#:kivy 1.10.1
#:include homescreen.kv
#:include openscreen.kv
#:include blockscreen.kv
#:include engscreen.kv

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        HomeScreen:
            name: "home_screen"
            id: home_screen
        OpenScreen:
            name: "open_screen"
            id: open_screen
        BlockScreen:
            name: "block_screen"
            id: block_screen
        EngScreen:
            name: "eng_screen"
            id: eng_screen
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `b = BlockScreen()` in your `App` creates a new `BlockScreen` that you reference with `app.b`, but that `BlockScreen` is not displayed by your app. The `BlockScreen` that is displayed is created by your main `kv` file. To access the displayed `BlockScreen`, I think you need something like `app.root.ids.block_screen.d_sl()`. And remove the line `b = BlockScreen()`.